# Bounding 4th moments of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

I'm trying to get an upper bound on $R^2$ defined as
$$x\sim \text{Normal}(0, \Sigma)$$
$$R^2=\frac{\|Ex'x xx'\|_2}{\|\Sigma\|_2}$$

$E$ is expectation, $\|\cdot\|$ is matrix spectral norm and $x$ is a column vector

In one dimension, the bound $R^2\le 3\text{tr}(\Sigma)$ is tight, how can I get a bound for many dimensions?

*Edit* empirically the following seems to hold
$$R^2=\text{tr}(\Sigma)+2\|\Sigma\|_2$$

Comment: I don’t know the answer, but check out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Higher_moments.